# Dreamweaver cs6 File upload and retrieve from database (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, database, dreamweaver

I am looking for a procedure in dreamweaver cs6 to upload a file to my database in godaddy.com account. Basically i am developing a HR consulting website, here i need a web page that can allow candidates to upload their resumes, these resumes should be saved in mysql. is there any best way or tutorial to create database content webpage? 
Thank you

Comment: i never used dreamweaver, but as far as i know its more a designers tool... what is exactly what you want to do? make a website and store the info of the website on a database??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a database in MySQL to hold the values of an HTML Form.
For example: you could have and HTML Form to ask form the name, last name, gender, age, and experience

```
First Name: <input type="text" id="first_name" />
Last Name: <input type="text" id="last_name" />
Gender: Male <input type="radio" id="male" value="male" name="gender"/>
        Female <input type="radio" id="female" value="female" name="gender"/>
Age : <input type="text" id="age" />
Experience: <textarea id="expirience"></textarea>
```

Or something of that manner. Then in your database have columns corresponding to these fields such as

```
first_name varchar(250) NOT NULL
last_name varchar(250) NOT NULL
gender enum('male', 'female') NOT NULL
age INT NOT NULL
experience TEXT NOT NULL
```